new rails class raises unexpected issue with fixture
A rails application class was amended to allow a new references for additional records: add_reference :transactions, :card, null: true, foreign_key: true
ruby '3.3.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.1', '>= 7.1.3.4'

rails -v resolves to Rails 7.2.2.1
the schema has:
    t.bigint "card_id"
    t.index ["card_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_card_id"

Transaction class states: belongs_to :card, optional: true
and querying postgresql confirms:
 card_id             | bigint                         |           |          |                                          | plain   |             |              |
[...]
   "index_transactions_on_card_id" btree (card_id)
[...]
   "fk_rails_10c5a1feaf" FOREIGN KEY (card_id) REFERENCES cards(id)

without having not null for the Nullable column, nor 0 for the Default column (they are blank).
The creation action now has a block to handle the new cases:
tx_params = params[:transaction]
[...]  
if !tx_params[:card_id]
  tx_params[:card_id] = nil
end

although its presence or absence does not change the test behaviour.
When running tests on the transactions controller, without changing the previously set of fixtures, a large number of tests (all those involved with creating a record) complain with:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "transactions" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_10c5a1feaf"
DETAIL:  Key (card_id)=(0) is not present in table "cards".

which is a sign that at least one fixture is wrong.
The transactions.yml file has zero card_id strings within.
I fail to see what, between the fixtures, the migration or the database structure is lacking.
*checking the test log to examine what is created on each test invocation:
INSERT INTO "transactions" ("id", "shop_id", "consumer_id", [...] "promotion_id", "card_id") VALUES (89389043, 39503638, 1058249888 [...] DEFAULT, DEFAULT), [...]

Every record is identical (to check I had some fixtures where card was shown as an attribute but with no value, others where the attribute was omitted)
So how is DEFAULT translating to '0' ?

There's insufficient information to debug the issue. Assuming that none of the fixtures directly sets card_id to zero, then perhap there is code in the class that is doing so; however, neither the fixture nor class definitions have been provided so we can only guess. Please update the post with a [mre] that exhibits the undesired behavior. It is likely that while doing so, you will discover the source of the error.

the question specifically states "Transaction class states: belongs_to :card, optional: true"; no other references to card in the class.  Card class does not invoke transaction.    But that got me to hinking to examin the test log records created.  See updated question: the problem is still full

@dbugger.  Question updated with info at top.

Admittedly, the question was lacking.
the clue is Key (card_id)=(0).
When does a nil value translate to '0'?
When it is typed with .to_i
there was a method that was processing the parameter that way
